# NSDateFormatter how_to

Tags: swift, nsdate

I am reading a JSON object and it includes a when field.  The when field is formatted "m-d-yyyy h:m:s"

So for instance, a date string could be "5-25-2016 5:30:2"

Since I do not know the length of m, d, h, m, and s, how can I get an NSDate out of these strings?

EDIT:  Using one of the tools from the comments, I've made some progress.  The website properly identifies the date (adds 6 hours for time shift, but I can fix that).  However, I'm still having issues on the device.

```
let dateFrmtr = NSDateFormatter()
dateFrmtr.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:MM:SS"
dateFrmtr.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")

print(dateFrmtr.dateFromString(mov["when"]! as! String)!) <-- prints "2016-10-08 01:00:00 +0000"
print(mov["when"]!) <-- prints "6-7-2016 19:10:3"
```

This is not the correct behaviour.

Comment: Have you looked at [`NSDateFormatter`'s doucmentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class)? It leads you to [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html), which links you to the various specs various version of OS X and iOS. [Here is the newest one.](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: I did read through the documentation.  It expects dd for 05 for May, and the strings I'm getting out of the JSON object do not necessarily have the leading 0

Comment: This thing is pretty handy as well http://nsdateformatter.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using pretty much exactly what you have shown!

```
let df = NSDateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "M-d-yyyy H:m:s"
df.dateFromString("5-25-2016 5:30:2") // works
df.dateFromString("12-25-2016 15:30:22") // works as well
```

The [docs](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) state *"Use one or two for zero padding"* for all of `M`, `s` and `H`, the others work the same way. That means: use two letters for zero padding, e.g. `MM` for 05 - or only one letter for omitting leading zeros: `M` for `5`. That works both for parsing and for outputting dates.

The changes I made for you contain of chaning the first `M` to upper case since that is the correct letter for months. Same for the hours.

Note that the parsing is powerful enough to work even when providing more letters:

```
df.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
df.dateFromString("1-5-2016 1:3:2") // works too
```

The formatting is more important for transforming the date back *to* a string!